# How to use external model data with Emukit python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am implementing this code (found here: https://emukit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Emukit-tutorial-custom-model.html)

```
import numpy as np
from emukit.experimental_design import ExperimentalDesignLoop
from emukit.core import ParameterSpace, ContinuousParameter
from emukit.core.loop import UserFunctionWrapper
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

x_min = -30.0
x_max = 30.0

X = np.random.uniform(x_min, x_max, (10, 1))
Y = np.sin(X) + np.random.randn(10, 1) * 0.05
sklearn_gp = GaussianProcessRegressor();
sklearn_gp.fit(X, Y);

from emukit.core.interfaces import IModel

class SklearnGPModel(IModel):
    def __init__(self, sklearn_model):
        self.model = sklearn_model

    def predict(self, X):
        mean, std = self.model.predict(X, return_std=True)
        return mean[:, None], np.square(std)[:, None]

    def set_data(self, X: np.ndarray, Y: np.ndarray) -> None:
        self.model.fit(X, Y)

    def optimize(self, verbose: bool = False) -> None:
        # There is no separate optimization routine for sklearn models
        pass

    @property
    def X(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.model.X_train_

    @property
    def Y(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.model.y_train_

emukit_model = SklearnGPModel(sklearn_gp)


p = ContinuousParameter('c', x_min, x_max)
space = ParameterSpace([p])

loop = ExperimentalDesignLoop(space, emukit_model)
loop.run_loop(np.sin, 50)
```

I am trying to implement this code but with the exteral data set. To do this, I need to understand if I can extract the 50 x-values propagated through the `np.sin` function when the `loop.run_loop(np.sin, 50)` is executed. Then, having obtained these 50 inputs (x-values), I need to propagate them in an external software, which saves the result as .csv file.

The information that I would have, that needs to be "put through" the `loop.run_loop()` is as follows:

[image]

So, I need to make the `loop.run_loop()` code work by loading an external results data but do now know how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, passing data does not make sense in this context. The default acquisition function will select the next input (or experiment) based on the your model. Your model is updated at each iteration from the outcome of your experiment and the next experiment is dependent on previous observations - it's not random.
Passing your samples independently of this loop would be significantly less informative.

In short, you need to define a function similar to np.sin that can be queried.

Hope this makes sense!